# How to identify the lock acquired by another user on a record in progress openedge

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

User A has read first record from a customer table. User B wishes to know the lock which is held by A on the record. How will B identify the lock held by User A programmatically.

Comment: What does "wishes to know the lock is held" mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LOCKED` function:

> Returns a TRUE value if a record is not available to a prior FIND . .
>   . NO-WAIT statement because another user has locked a record.

Example of the documentation:

```
REPEAT:
    PROMPT-FOR customer.cust-num.
    FIND customer USING customer.cust-num NO-ERROR NO-WAIT.
    IF NOT AVAILABLE customer THEN DO:
        IF LOCKED customer
        THEN MESSAGE "Customer record is locked".
        ELSE MESSAGE "Customer record was not found".
        NEXT.
    END.
    DISPLAY cust-num name city state.
END.
```

Other example:

```
FIND FIRST table
     WHERE table.c1 = "foo"
     EXCLUSIVE-LOCK NO-ERROR NO-WAIT.
IF LOCKED(table)   
THEN DO:
    /* The record is blocked by another user */
END. 
ELSE DO:
    IF AVAILABLE table 
    THEN DO:
        /* The record can be modified */
    END.
END.
```

Comment: how can i find whether it is Exclusive, Share or No-lock?

Comment: With `LOCKED` function, you can know if the record is locked (with EXCLUSIVE-LOCK or SHARE-LOCK) or not (with NO-LOCK or SHARE-LOCK)

Comment: Still it is not clear that whether it is exclusive, share or no-lock.

Comment: If a record is modified by EXCLUSIVE-LOCK or SHAR-LOCK, the LOCKED function return TRUE otherwise, the function return FALSE. So you just can to know if the record is locked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in _Lock Virtual System Table.

This is a basic example:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttLock
  FIELD LockId LIKE _Lock._Lock-Id
  FIELD LockUsr LIKE _Lock._Lock-Usr
  FIELD LockName LIKE _Lock._Lock-Name
  FIELD LockTable LIKE _Lock._Lock-Table
  FIELD LockFlags LIKE _Lock._Lock-flags
  INDEX LockIdx IS PRIMARY UNIQUE LockId.

FOR EACH _Lock NO-LOCK:
  IF _Lock._Lock-Usr = ? THEN NEXT .
  CREATE ttLock.
  ASSIGN
      LockId    = _Lock._Lock-Id
      LockUsr   = _Lock._Lock-Usr
      LockName  = _Lock._Lock-Name
      LockTable = _Lock._Lock-Table
      lockFlags = _Lock._Lock-flags.
END.

FOR EACH ttlock:
  FIND _Trans NO-LOCK WHERE  _Trans._Trans-Usrnum = ttLock.LockUsr NO-ERROR.
  FIND _File NO-LOCK WHERE _File-Number = ttLock.LockTable.

  MESSAGE
   "Transaction Id:~t" (IF AVAILABLE _Trans THEN _Trans._Trans-Id ELSE ?) "~n"
   "User Number:~t" ttLock.LockUsr "~n"
   "User Name~t" ttLock.LockName "~n"
   "Table Number:~t" ttLock.LockTable "~n"
   "Table Name:~t" _File-Name "~n"
   "Flags:~t" ttLock.LockFlags
   VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
END.
```

(Taken directly from [this entry in the knowledgebase](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000033245).)

In the [Database Administration](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge115/pdfs/dmadm/dmadm.pdf) guide you can see (page 848) you can see what the flags in _Lock.LockFlags stand for.

> Flags for the lock—the flags specify a share
>   lock (S), exclusive lock (X), a lock upgraded
>   from share to exclusive(U), a lock in limbo (L),
>   a queued lock(Q), a lock kept across
>   transaction end boundary (K), a lock is part of
>   a JTAtransaction (J), a lock is in create mode
>   for JTA (C), or a lockwait timeout has expired
>   on this queued lock (E)

**Querying the _Lock table might be something you want to do in test environments only. Depending on your systems size there might be LOT of data there. Also, use VSTs for READ-ONLY operations!**

Comment: Querying _LOCK in production on releases previous to 11.4 is a very, very, very bad idea.  11.4 and above have changed the implementation to a "snapshot" which makes it less of a problem.  But old code should not try to manipulate _lock.

Answer (score -1):

Querying _LOCK in older releases is OK, but you have to use the appropriate code for the respective version:

- _LOCK always has the full number of entries given in -L, regardless how many locks currently exist.
- In pre-11.4 releases the fields are not indexed, but all used locks are at the beginning of the table, so you can use

  ```
  IF _Lock._Lock-Usr = ? THEN LEAVE.
  ```

  in the for each loop (_Lock._Lock-Name = ? is also fine). See http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P161995
- In 11.4 and 11.5 the populated entries are no longer at the beginning so the old code will give wrong results (see http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000056304, this is fixed in 11.5.1). Fortunately scanning the lock table is now much faster so you can use

  ```
  FOR EACH _Lock NO-LOCK WHERE _Lock-Recid <> ?:
  ```

  mentioned in the same article. Technically this is not implemented with indices. (An index wouldn't work with the <> operator.)
- In 11.5 and 11.6 both variants should work, but the newer variant with a where phrase should be faster.

Comment: It is not true that all locks are below the first one with _lock-usr = ?.  It appears to be true on small test systems.  On large production systems you will discover that this is not reliable.